# Sas - keeping entry with largest absolute value

Tags: sas, duplicates

Let's say I have four samples: id=1, 2, 3, and 4, with one or more measurements on each of those samples:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAgsm.png)

```
  ID  Value 
   1   1
   1   2
   2   3
   2  -4 
   3  -5
   4   6
```

I want to remove duplicates, keeping only one entry per ID - the one having the largest absolute value of the "value" column. I.e., this is what I want:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Y73.png)

```
   ID  Value 
   1   2
   2  -4
   3  -5
   4   6
```

How might I do this in SAS?

I didn't find a solution to do this with SAS, so I tried to export it to Excel and use pivot table and "Value Field max" -setting, but that only gave me highest value, and and I need highest difference from zero.

Comment: What do you want when there are ties for the largest magnitude?  For example if you had both 4 and -4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL with a `having` clause will solve this quickly.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select id, value
        from have
        group by id
        having abs(value) = max(abs(value))
    ;
quit;
```

Output:

```
ID  Value
1   2
2   -4
3   -5
4   6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,there are a few ways to do this.
I would create a new variable with your absolute value, sort the dataset by id and descending absolute value and then keep the top record.

The code would look like:

```
data tmp1;
  set data1;
  absvalue = abs(value);

proc sort data=tmp1;
  by id descending absvalue ;

data tmp2;
  set tmp1; 
  by id;

  if first.id then output tmp2;
run;
```

You could also use Proc Sql.